# How to apply a css class for jqGrid height property setGridHeight?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jqgrid

Our goal is to apply `media query css class`.

As of now, the code below uses `$(window).height()` for finding the `height`.

```
$('#list').jqGrid('setGridHeight', $(window).height() - 380);
```

Instead of using `$(window).height() - 380`, I need to apply a `css class`. Thanks.

Comment: Using CSS you can't calculate `$(window).height()`

Comment: I need to mention that `Media Query css class name` instead of `$(window).height() - 380`. So, How to add a `css class` here. Thanks.

Comment: you can't assign classnames there. Only you can assign variables. Or you can add class for `#list`

Comment: I tried `$('#list').addClass('grid_height');` where `grid_height` has `height:50px`; But, the changes does not reflect in the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the following

```
// place hidden test div
var $testDiv = $("<div style='display:none'></div>");
$testDiv.addClass("grid_height").appendTo("body");
// I hope you will grid_height from correct media

// alternatively you can try to use
//     $("#list").addClass("grid_height");
// but BEFORE you create jqGrid

var height = parseInt($testDiv.css("height"), 10);
$testDiv.remove();

// now you can use height variable to set grid height
$("#list").jqGrid("setGridHeight", height);
```

**UPDATED**: [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CssWidthTest.htm) seems to work.

Comment: I am getting the value as `"0px"` for `$testDiv.css("height")`. My `css` looks as following `.grid_height { height:50px; }`. I need to get `50px` or whatever I am having in my `css class name`.Thanks.

Comment: @JohnStephen: Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CssWidthTest.htm) and compare it with youth.